# Jspdf Alignment/ layout not working

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am doing an HTML to pdf conversion with jspdf

Here is my running code...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPZaYN

You can see the output (below) is different from the PDF..There are no borders and alignment.

I am not able to achieve simple layout / alignment , padding/float etc..

This is how it should look  (you can also see here my Html code)

http://screencast.com/t/xE6fbJKrA9m

But when i Get the pdf of this from jspdf it looks like this

http://screencast.com/t/z8cizeY9

This is my jspdf Code ..

```
     var doc = $wnd.jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
   var source = $('#content').first();
   var specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
          return true;
      }
  };
   doc.fromHTML(
      htmltest, 
     {
          'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      });

  doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

This is my head

```
           <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.min.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/adler32cs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsPDF's html plugin does not support most css.  But despair not, here is a work around.

Try it out:

```js
$( 'a' ).hide();
html2canvas( document.body, { onrendered : function( canvas ) { 'use strict';
  var pdf = new jsPDF(), border = 10, width = 210-border*2;
  pdf.addImage( canvas.toDataURL( 'image/jpeg' , 0.98 ), 'JPEG',
                border, border, width, canvas.height*width/canvas.width );
  // pdf.save() does not work on StackOverflow because of cross origin restriction
  $('a').show()[0].href = pdf.output( 'dataurlstring' );
  // IE 11 does not allow datauri pdf, use save() instead
} } );
```

```css
body{font:12px "Times New Roman",serif;}h1{font-size:24px;line-height:24px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;text-align:right;margin-bottom:5px;}#render_me > div > div{float:right}#render_me > div > div > div{border-bottom:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;padding:3px; text-align:center}.b_top{border-top:1px solid black;}.f_c_b_left:last-child{border-left:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<a href="#">PDF<br>(Ctrl+Click me or open me in new window)</a>

<div id="render_me"><div>
 <h1>Invoice</h1>
 <div><div class="b_top">Invoice #</div><div>00001-2</div></div>
 <div class="f_c_b_left"><div class="b_top">Date</div><div>2015-02-05</div></div>
</div></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://parall.ax/parallax/js/jspdf.js'></script>
```

The idea is, renders the HTML onto a canvas using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), then put the screenshot into PDF.
This is not perfect, but at least the elements will be in correct positions and alignments.

Drawbacks:

1. Like jsPDF's HTML renderer, html2canvas understand few CSS.  The major difference is that html2canvas can access the layout did by the browser.
2. The image only have 96dpi, causing low quality.
3. Result PDF will be relatively big.

For now, this is my best HTML to PDF solution.
To get better result, I will manually build the PDF (without HTML).

> I cannot get the pdf link in this example to open in new window or download, as long as it is ran in StackOverflow's Code snippet.  If you put the code elsewhere you can call pdf.save like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwksc4ku/1

Comment: thanks for the help , In your jspdf/javascript code .. where are we telling the source of html......   If i replace ur javascript/jspdf code with mine , it says , $ is undefined

Comment: @junaidp `$` comes from jQuery.  `$` is `undefined` means jQuery is not yet loaded.  In code snippet the JS runs at the end, after the three `<script>`, so if you put the js earlier you must move up the `<script>`s too.

Comment: Currently i am getting "html2canvas is not defined" ..I have downloaded and put html2canvas.js and html2canvas.min.js inside my war folder and added inside html...<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>

Comment: @junaidp It is easier to play in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xwksc4ku/1/ (Tested on IE 11, Chrome 40, Firefox 35). It is likely that your code has other errors, given by Codepen link's code quality, and they may be out of scope for this question.

Comment: exactly doing the same as you are and adding the same libs.. Its saying .. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null:  in this line"in screenshot" .. Please have a look on the screenshot.. http://screencast.com/t/sh0TS4Va  ::http://screencast.com/t/9bBuLysL5h  : ::

Comment: @junaidp If you cannot reproduce it on jsfiddle, I won't be able to reproduce the error either...